# .change() after select as been changed do a page refresh, like CTRL + R

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i set this javascript that once the select menu option has been changed to then simulate a page refresh straight after like if i select a option then press CTRL +R it will refresh the page but keep the selection, then if i do the same process again and refresh.

But I dont want the user to do this I want it to do it automatically using the .change() method.

```
  $("#select-options").change(function(){
  selectedValue = $(this).val();
  var p = selectedValue.indexOf("£");
  rest = selectedValue.substring(p+1);
  $(".item").attr("data-price",rest)}).change();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are programmatically triggering the event, you have to differentiate between a user change and your own. Detecting originalEvent in the event callback should suffice.

```
$("#select-options").change(function(e) {
    selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var p = selectedValue.indexOf("£");
    rest = selectedValue.substring(p+1);
    $(".item").attr("data-price",rest);

    if(e.originalEvent) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}).change();
```

Comment: YOUR A LEGEND! Sweet, works like a treat!, Thanks dude.

Comment: As you probably guessed im know to all the jQuery/Javascript, I can read it and understand it just not able to write it yet! It's on my learning list!.....

Comment: No worries, we all start somewhere. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Good old JavaScript (although I'm not sure why you would want to do that exactly):

```
window.location.reload();
```

I don't know if all browsers will keep your selection, though. For me, it works in FF and Chrome.

Comment: yeah tried that but it constantly refreshes....

I just want it to refresh once a new selection has been made.

Comment: It probably does that because you fire the change event (.change()) every time the page loads.

Comment: So how can I get around this?

Comment: Just remove the .change() part, which fires the actual event. Or do you need that for anything?

Comment: Yes as it is then been passed to a custom html attribute

Comment: Only reload if the event is from the user (`e.originalEvent` exists).

Comment: So you will have to find a design that solves the underlying problem: If you want to define a page refresh in the onChange method AND you need to fire the event executing the onChange method immediately on page load, you will also have continuous refreshes. This is something you'll need to figure out. Or find a way to identify if the event was fired after user interaction or not.

Comment: @Syntax I'm not sure what you mean?